# How to make a single express endpoint for multiple optional parameters for database query?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am stuck at routing in Express. I want to make a single route for multiple optional request parameters to fetch records from the database based on the given parameter by the client.

I am using this:

"/search/:firstName?/:lastName?/:department?/:designation?"

Problem in the above url is : if user wants to search by only department then department will be mapped with firstName

Comment: Rethink your API. Use search params.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you want all parameters to be part of the route, rather than query parameters? Otherwise query parameters are the best way to get the kind of flexibility you seek.

Comment: Why not use query parameters instead? This way there is no order and you can omit any combination.

Comment: Thank you all for suggesting me the idea. I am new to Express and wasn't aware of query parameters. Using query parameters my URL looks like this and working fine:localhost:5000/recipients/search/?firstName=&lastName=&designation=&department=PROD-01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to go about it is using query parameters. So if the user only wants to search by department, an example request url will look like this:

```
/search?department=education
```

Multiple parameters will be separated by a `&`. For e.g:

```
/search?department=education&firstName=john
```

You can access this information in express like this:

```
// ...
router.get('search', function(req, response){
      var department = req.query.department;
      var firstName = req.query.firstName;
      // ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Query parameters is the best option in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for suggesting me the idea of Query Parameters. I am new to Express and wasn't aware of query parameters. 
Using query parameters my URL looks like this and working fine:

localhost:5000/recipients/search/?firstName=&lastName=&designation=&department=PROD-01